# What is the range of this complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis

The function is: $f(z) = 2x^2+(1-x^2)(1+i)$ on the unit disk $|z|\leq1$.

I simplified this down and got that $Re(f(z)) = x^2+1$ and $Im(f(z)) = 1 - x^2$, which then led me to think that the answer is:

"The line segment from $w = 1 + i$ to $w=2$."

Advice? Thanks!

Comment: Are we to assume $z = x+iy$ here, or are you accidentally using $x$ in place of $z$ on the right-hand side?

Comment: Yes, we are to assume that $z=x+iy$.

Comment: It should read $\operatorname{Re}(f(z))$ and $\operatorname{Im}(f(z))$.

Comment: Fair enough. Edited. Thanks for pointing that out @Cameron.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this function is independent of $y$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - any values of $y$ used won't affect the value of $f$.